# Is it possible for an ISAPI Extension to disconnect from the client

Tags: c, iis, isapi

I developed an ISAPI Extension for IIS in C using VS 2019. A desktop application performs a GET to a URL which triggers the extension.

The business user asked if it is possible for long running tasks if it could return a status & short message to the desktop app and continue processing. The result of the processing is stored in a database.

I tried returning HSE_STATUS_PENDING and running the process in another thread but the client still waits for it to finish.

I've done several searches and haven't found any method for the server process to disconnect the client.

Comment: The idea of "long running tasks" on IIS is bad. Run them in a Windows service app.

Comment: That was my first response to them. Thanks